# Selenium WebScraping: Try get ProductList but always get same Product

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to get a Product List of a website with selenium. I prototyped the program and everything worked perfectly but now I built a loop to get all products and it just gives me the same product 484 times(that's the number of products there are on the website)

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup  # HTML data structure
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq  # Web client
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

# URl to web scrape from
page_url = "https://www.smythstoys.com/at/de-at/spielzeug/lego/c/SM100114"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(page_url)

buttonName = "loadMoreProducts"
loadMoreButton = driver.find_element_by_id(buttonName)
while loadMoreButton is not None:
    try:
        try:
            loadMoreButton.click()
        except selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException:
            break
    except selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException:
        break

uClient = uReq(page_url)
page_soup = soup(uClient.read(), "html.parser")
uClient.close()

# gets all products
containers = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('article')
print(len(containers))

# name the output file to write to local disk
out_filename = "smythstoys_product_data.csv"
# header of csv file to be written
headers = "product_name;price; info \n"

# opens file, and writes headers
f = open(out_filename, "w")
f.write(headers)

# loops trough all products
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
# here is the problem:
for container in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('article'):

    print("----------------------------------------------------------------------")
    product_name_container = container.find_element_by_xpath("//h2[@class ='prodName trackProduct']")
    product_name = product_name_container.text
    print(product_name)

    price_container = container.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class ='price']")
    price = price_container.text
    print("price:", price)
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    try:
        info_container = container.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class ='decalImage-right']").text
        print(info_container)
        if not info_container:
            info = "no special type"
            print(info)
            print(info_container)
            f.write(product_name + "; " + price + "; " + info + "\n")
            continue
        if info_container == "https://smyths-at-prod-images.storage.googleapis.com/sys-master/images/hed/h5f/8823589830686" \
                             "/lego-hard-to-find-decal_CE.svg":
            info = "seltenes Set"
        elif info_container == "https://smyths-at-prod-images.storage.googleapis.com/sys-master/images/h41/h70" \
                               "/8823587930142/new-decal_CE%20%281%29.svg":
            info = "neues Set"
        elif info_container == "https://smyths-at-prod-images.storage.googleapis.com/sys-master/images/hde/hae" \
                               "/8871381303326/sale-decal_CE.svg":
            info = "Sale"
        else:
            info = "unknown type" + info_container
        print(info)
        print(info_container)
    except NameError:
        print("no atribute")
        if info_container is None:
            info = "unknown type"
            print(info)

    # writes the dataset to file
    f.write(product_name + "; " + price + "; " + info + "\n")

f.close()  # Close the file
```

My output is:

```
LEGO Star Wars 75244 Tantive IV
price: 199,99€

no special type
```

and that 484x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you used selenium to get the products when requests can do it smoothly. The following is something you wanna do to get all the products using requests.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

link = "https://www.smythstoys.com/at/de-at/at/de-at/spielzeug/lego/c/SM100114/load-more?"

params = {'q':':bestsellerRating:productVisible:true','page':'1'}

p = 0

while True:
    params['page'] = p
    r = requests.get(link,params=params,headers={
        'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    })
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.json()['htmlContent'],"lxml")
    if not soup.select_one("a.trackProduct[href]"):break
    for item in soup.select("a.trackProduct[href]"):
        product_name = item.select_one("h2.prodName").get_text(strip=True)
        product_price = item.select_one("[itemprop='price']").get("content")
        print(product_name,product_price)

    p+=1
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but your example doesn't work for me because of several reasons. First of all I don't know how the example executed without any errors on my machine there are several errors. To answer your question I picked selenium because it seems to be the easiest way to interact with the website(I need to interact with the website as I would if I am browsing) for additions in the future. (This is just a early version of a bigger project. Nevertheless thanks for your encouragement!

Comment: There are several errors you found in the above script but not a single one to mention, right? The only error you may have is parser related. However, If my guess is right, try replacing `lxml` with `html.parser` to get rid of that. Btw, ***[this](https://filebin.net/qcyl43nxfg4mns6q)*** is the output the script produces..

Comment: I so sorry. I messed something up in my editor, after seeing the correct output I messed with some settings of my editor and it eventually worked. Sorry I was 100% my fault. Thanks for your help. One last question how did you get all items. I also tried it with bs4  before but with my script I only got the first 30 items.

Comment: You perhaps missed the `params` part in your earlier attempt. This is the very portion that helps parse the content from next pages. You can find this `params` in dev tools under network tab within xhr. Thanks.

Comment: If the above solution worked for you, make sure to accept it as an answer @Ph.lpp. [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/673712) is how you can do it. Thanks.